# How to analyse Android Monkey Test logs?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, monkey-testing

As we know, monkey test is a automatic tool for testers. But How could we analyse the logs of monkey test. Now in my project, I meet the problem. The log is:

```
  --------- beginning of crash

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629): Process: com.lenovo.projectionapplication, PID: 10629

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:2057)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:110)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:462)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2054)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9328)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2606)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1759)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2810)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2567)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4126)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3678)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3731)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3697)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3705)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3678)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3731)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3697)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3705)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3678)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3731)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3697)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1865)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2230)

07-06 15:37:09.803 E/AndroidRuntime(10629):     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
```

Can you give some suggestions? The logs dont show me the line number of causing "pointerIndex out of range", which puzzled me

Comment: that's not complete report. It should contains `Caused by...` part and trhere should be problematic line

Comment: ok thanks, If all the monkey test log contains "caused by...", I will search in my log txt